# Drupal - how to find module names for Drush install?

Tags: docker, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8, drush

I have a Drupal installation within a Docker container. I need to install and enable a bunch of modules for which I can use `container require drupal/<modulename>` followed by `drush en <modulename> -y` and it works.

Now there are a few modules that I'm not sure of the the Drush name for. For instance `Automated Logout` - I did a perfunctory search on the Drupal modules page and it pointed me to `https://www.drupal.org/project/autologout` - should I use this project name of `autologout` for the Drush install?

Also, is this the standard way to go about installing my required modules?

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal 8 standard way of installing modules is probably using composer

```
composer require drupal/<modulename>
```

As `modulename` you can use the last part of the URL of the project's page

```
https://www.drupal.org/project/<modulename>
```

in your case `autologout`